# While starting rails server getting an error the application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the exact error-

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.12.0/lib/rmagick.
rb:11:in `require': 14001: The application has failed to start because its side-
by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use
the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/rmagick-2.12.0/RMagick2.so (LoadError)
```

Comment: Version 2.12.0 of rmagick is from October 2009.  There is a much newer version (2.13.2) from February 2013.  I suggest you update and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: yeah i updated it still i get the same error-

Comment: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.
rb:11:in `require': 14001: The application has failed to start because its side-
by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use
the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.
9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.so
(LoadError)

Comment: i m really stuck on this rmagick thing

Comment: graeme any idea whats the actual error is?

Comment: any problem with rmagick2.so file?

Comment: It's not actually Rails problem you have; the rmagick gem is giving you the error because it cannot load RMagick2.so.  Ignoring the rmagick gem, do you have ImageMagick installed ok?  I see you are on Windows - these links may or may not help - http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows, https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

Comment: i followed the same procedure while installing rmagick as given in these links.No problems with installation.But it can load the rmagick2.so file.why so?